# Bixby NL and Conversation Driver with an enum type

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have an "Smoking Status" input-view matching a enum type, in which I am accepting a selection-of as well as a few conversation drivers asking whether or not the user smokes. I'm having a little trouble getting my capsule to recognize an input coming from a conversation driver and I'm not sure on the cause or how to trace the issue.

Here is the SmokingType Concept

```
enum (SmokingType) {
  description (Do you smoke)
  symbol (Yes)
  symbol (No)
}
```

Here is the Smoking Concept

```
structure (Smoking) {
  description(smoking status of person)
  property (smoking) {
    type (SmokingType)
    min (Required)
  }
}
```

One of the conversation drivers in the input-view is something like:

```
conversation-driver {
  template ("No I am not a smoker")
}
```

The "ExampleAction" collection requires this as one of it's inputs

```
input (smoking) {
  type (SmokingType)
  min (Required) max (One)
  prompt-behavior (AlwaysElicitation)
  default-init {
    intent {
      goal: SmokingType
      value-set {SmokingType {SmokingType(Yes) SmokingType(No)}}
    }
  }
}
```

As far I understand it, the NL Training should be able to successful complete the required input, but I'm not having any success. My closes guess has been.

```
[g:ExampleAction] (No)[v:SmokingType:No] I am not a smoker
```

Unfortunately, the selection prompt keeps coming back up. I haven't seen an example that addresses this issue close enough to make it relatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check if the enum is included in the vocabulary file. If not, the training will not recognize it.

Here is the relevant screenshot from the [documentation](https://www.bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/modeling.modeling-concepts) [image]

Comment: Yes! Right on. The missing vocab file was the issue. Just as an extra note, the documentation is a little misleading as the values NEED to have at least one synonym. Even if it's the same as the value: 

 vocab (MYCAPSULE.SmokingType) {
  "Yes" {"Yes"}
  "No" {"No"}
}

Comment: We will revisit the examples on our side to make it unambiguous. Thank you for the feedback!